# Using a SOAP 1.1 web service in a VB.NET application

Tags: vb.net, web-services, soap

In our application a Service Reference was added to connect to a SOAP Web Service. When connecting to the Web Service we get an error. The owner of the web service told us that the error was caused because we use SOAP 1.2 and theirs web service only supports SOAP 1.1.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1555507) mentions to add a `textMassageEncoding` setting in our custom binding. But it is not clear where to add this setting. Where should this setting been added?

Comment: Is there any way you can have this be a Web Reference instead of a Service Reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding a `Service Reference` add a `Web Reference`.  I use VS 2013 (VS 2017 is exactly the same), right click on project name in Solution Explorer, select `add` then `Service Reference`, click `Advanced` button, click `Add Web Reference` at the bottom.  Web references are a bit dated, but I use them all the time because I have a ton of legacy software, including android and iOS apps that use them.  RESTful apis are typically the most used api these days.

Comment: I'll add to this that the OP can then specify the Soap version doing this with the generated proxy classes like so: YourProxyInstance.SoapVersion = SoapProtocolVersion.Soap11